# Fragment compatibility androidx issue?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I use this code to add a fragment programmatically in mainactivity

```
   androidx.fragment.app.Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_newview);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(frag);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
```

I get error on ft.add(frag)
Cannot resolve method 'add(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)' i guess this is a compatibility issue?
How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:
`FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();`

And make sure you are importing the `FragmentTransaction` from the `androidX` library (`androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction`).

Additionally, `FragmentTransaction.add()` does not allow just one parameter. You need to supply a tag in your case. So for example:
 
`ft.add(frag, "fragment");`.
Or you can use the other `add()` methods.

Finally, I don't know why you are finding the `Fragment` then adding it - it is either already added (because you are finding it by id) or this will throw a `NullPointerException` because the `Fragment` is `null`. Instead of finding your fragment by id instantiate it like this: 
`androidx.fragment.app.Fragment frag = NewviewFragment()`

**The final code should look like this:**

```
androidx.fragment.app.Fragment frag = NewviewFragment()
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(frag, "tag");
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
```

That should solve your issue.

Comment: Now i get this error Incompatible types. Found: 'androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction', required: 'android.app.FragmentTransaction'

Comment: You imported the wrong `FragmentTransaction`. Remove the import and when re-importing make sure you import the `FragmentTransaction` from `androidX`. I've updated my answer, take a look.

Comment: Be sure your fragments extend library `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` and not native `android.app.Fragment` (latter being deprecated).

Comment: I checked and changed them to androidx imports. Now i get this Cannot resolve method 'add(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)' in .add(frag) this is the new code  Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_newview);

            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
           
            ft.add(frag);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();

Comment: `add()` does not allow just one parameter. You need to supply a tag in your case. So for example: `ft.add(frag, "fragment");`. Or you can use the other `add()` methods.

Comment: But the error didnt mention two parameters. Anyway.    ft.add(frag,"nav_newview"); now it crashes at this line Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference

Comment: The fragment you are adding was never instantiated. I'm a bit confused at your whole setup. You are trying to find the fragment nav_newview and then add it. The problem is though, that the fragment was never added in the first place?

Comment: First create the Fragment you wish to add: ```Fragment frag = new Fragment(); // or call getInstance()
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(frag, "tag");
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();```

Comment: The fragment has already a class. How do i create a fragment from this specific class in main activity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230904/discussion-between-izak-and-stefanosn).